# How to make and import reusable components in NEXTJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js

How to make and import reusable components in NEXTJS

I am new to nextjs but I am familiar with react.

Next JS confused me a bit when making reusable components.

For example:-

In React - we create reusable components like the code mentioned below

Code Path ----> src/components/button.js

```
import React from 'react';

const ButtonComponent = (props) => {
    return (
        <>
            <button>{props.children}</button>
        </>
    )
}

export default ButtonComponent;
```

But can this same code be used in NEXTJS as well?

If yes, then where should be the path of the components directory?

**Update 1:**

My next js folder structure

https://prnt.sc/26bqbks

But now the problem is if I am trying to use react bootstrap it gives me an error that

> module not found

Screenshot -> https://prnt.sc/26bqca7

**Update 2:**

Ok I have re-installed react-bootstrap and now I get the error mentioned in the screenshot ---> https://prnt.sc/26bqinu

**Update 3**

Repo code

https://github.com/Yusufzai/test-next-js-bootstrap

Comment: How are you importing react-bootstrap? Can I see your package.json file? Or can you send a link to your repo?

Comment: @JevonCochran Thanks for your response. Screenshot 1 --> https://prnt.sc/26bqotj and screenshot 2 ---> https://prnt.sc/26bqp3c

Comment: Below is my repo link ---> https://github.com/Yusufzai/test-next-js-bootstrap

Comment: Updated my question with repo link

Comment: Looking over it now

Comment: Do you have zoom? I wasn't able to recreate your error. I fired up your application just fine. If you have zoom, I can help you troubleshoot.

Comment: Sorry no i don't have zoom. Does it work fine on your side?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240892/discussion-between-jevon-cochran-and-owaiz-yusufi).

Answer (score 0):

Your path should be relative to your current page.

Suppose you are having a page `pages/test.js`.

**test.js**

```js
import Component "../components/Component";
// use here
```

Comment: thank for your reply provide you my nextjs folder strucutre

Comment: Updated my question please review

Comment: In which file, you are trying to import the component?

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded your repo. Was able to fire it up just fine. Just delete your node_modules folder. Restart your server. Then run npm i.